# Is this DQL query correct?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony2.

I have an entity Employee and an entity Message related by an OneToMany association.

So a employee can have some messages and I want to have the one which has been sent the most recently, for a given employee.

Is this query correct ?

```
<?php
  public function getLast($id_employee)
  {
   $query = $this->_em->createQuery(
                 'SELECT MAX(m.sentAt) FROM MyBundle:Message m JOIN m.employee e 
                   WHERE e.id = ' . $id_employee);
    return $query->getSingleResult();
   }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't need to do a `JOIN` since the external key is alredy onto your `message` table and since we can think that **a message** belongs only to **one user** and one user can have multiple messages related to him.

So your query will be

```
'SELECT MAX(m.sentAt), m.text 
 FROM MyBundle:Message m 
 WHERE m.employee_id = :id_employee'
```

and you have to modify your code in that way

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
              'SELECT MAX(m.sentAt),m.text 
               FROM MyBundle:Message m 
               WHERE m.employee_id = :id_employee')
               ->setParameter('id_employee',$employee_id)
               return $query->getSingleResult();
```

However if you had to do a join, please remember this important things

1. If your entities are related with association and your only `ON` condition is about keys, you haven't to specify it with `WHERE` clause
2. Doctrine provide you a "faster" method for do this type of query without using directly `DQL` (or use it only a little) and use something like `->leftJoin(..)` , `->where(..)` and so on